# In ML text classification what if text doesn't belongs to any category?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm using text classification for news types like sports,politics,business,entertainment using logistic regression and the text which doesn't belongs to the above categories are also predicted as one of the category. How to prevent this in machine learning? also how to add out of category text to other_category label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `predict` method will give you the prediction which has the highest probability. You can use `predict_proba` method which will give you the probability score for each category. So you can use the 
`max()` function to get the maximum probability, then you can simply use the `if` statement to check if the probability is greater than the required value print the prediction otherwise `else` print others.
If you don't get look at the sample code.

```
model.fit(text, tags)

textToBeClassified = ["Google's shares are going down"]  # it is to be in a [] list that's how the predict method expects the input, you can classify more text by adding here separated by a comma.

prediction = model.predict(textToBeClassified)  # it will return the tag as politics or sports or business etc.
predictionConfidence = model.predict_proba(textToBeClassified)  # it will return a tuple of confidence score (probability) for each inputs.

maxConfidence = max(predictionConfidence[0])  # I'm having only one text to be classified which is the first text so I'm finding the maximum value of the first text.

if maxConfidence > 0.8:  # I want the output only if it is 80% confident about the classification, you can change 0.8 to 0.9 if you want 90% accurate.
    print(prediction)
else:
    print("Sorry the text doesn't fall under any of the categories")
```

try adding print statements here and there so you know what is happening

```
model.fit(text, tags)

textToBeClassified = ["Google's shares are going down"]

prediction = model.predict(textToBeClassified)
print("Predicted as:", prediction)

predictionConfidence = model.predict_proba(textToBeClassified)
print("The Confidance scores:", predictionCondidence)

maxConfidence = max(predictionConfidence[0])
print("maximum confidence score is:", maxConfidence)

if maxConfidence > 0.8:
    print(prediction)
else:
    print("Sorry the text doesn't fall under any of the categories")
```

Like this :)

Comment: well explained thank you. I have  **other_category** label and if the text doesn't belongs to sports,politics,business,entertainment category I want to predict it as other_category because we don't know exactly which category data will come. So I'm asking , can we do like that?

Comment: No that is not possible, the category should be specific. I think you didn't get how classification works :) no offence. DO NOT create something like that, because that will affect the prediction, it is like adding irrelevant training data, it will confuse the model.

Comment: If text doesn't fall under any category then it is not added to any category right? only right predictions were added to the categories. Am I right?

Comment: **"If the text doesn't fall under any category"** this is itself wrong it will fall under some category but the accuracy will be low.

Comment: **it will fall under some category but the accuracy will be low** in this case if it doesn't belong to four categories then it should fall in 5th category right?

Comment: it will fall under the category which has the highest value(but the value may be low like 0.5 i.e 50%) this is a bad prediction

Comment: take the above example I gave, it should be classified as a business but if you see the value of ```predictionConfidence``` it might be something like (9.999999e-1, 5.555e-9, 7.77745e-6) and so on that 9.99999e-1 represent the probability of Business, 5.555 represents the probability of entertainment and so on but the business category has the highest value so it is given as the prediction.